# Java: Parameter traversal?

Tags: java, refactoring

I have this code:

```java
public class Compiler {

    public void compile(String template, Object o, Object params) {
         //...
        context(o, params);
         //...
    }

    private void context(Object o, Object params) {
         //...
         substitue(o, params);
         //...
    }

    private void substitue(Object o, Object params) {
         //...
         print(params);
         //...
    }

    private void print(Object params) {//use parameter params here, only here 
         //...
         System.out.println(params);
         //...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the parameter `params` is used only in the `print` method, not in `compile`, `context` or `substitue`. The problem is adding the `params` to the signature of all the methods down to `print`.

In general, when I'm facing this problem I refactor my code like the following :

```java
public class Compiler {


    public void compile(String template, Object o, Object params) {
        //...
        new InnerCompiler(template, o, params).compile();
        //...
    }

    private static class InnerCompiler {
        private final String template;
        private final Object o;
        private final Object params;

        InnerCompiler(String template, Object o, Object params) {
            this.template = template;
            this.o = o;
            this.params = params;
        }

        private void compile() {
            //...
            context();
            //...
        }


        private void context() {
            //...
            substitue();
            //...
        }

        private vois substitue() {
           //...
           print();
           //...
        }

        private void print() {
            //...
            System.out.println(this.params);
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very basic example to illustrate the case of passing a parameter to all the methods even if it is not used by the method itself but by the next one (or deeper).

**I'm looking for the name of this problem (maybe an anti-pattern)**. In the title I've put *(Parameter traversal)* but it could be wrong or it means another thing.

Comment: I've read your question three times and I still don't understand what you're asking. Can you please help me understand? I mean, I understand the question is "what is this approach called?" but I don't understand what approach you're talking about. Removing the first n parameters from the varargs?

Comment: Honestly no. But don't mind me, I'm probably just tired. I hope you get an appropriate answer from someone else who actually understood.

Comment: forget what i've just explained, try to find what's wrong with theses methods. they are all in the same class (i'll add this detail)

Comment: @jannis yeah, the only wrong thing is that it doesn't compile unless you declare `compile` and `context` as `final`.

Comment: I would call what you want to do (store the array in a class property instead of passing it as argument to method) an anti-pattern: your class wouldn't be thread-safe anymore, and the class fields wouldn't represent the state of an object, but some temporary storage used for one of its methods. I would keep your code as is, but wouldn't use varargs for the private methods, since they're apparently always called with an array as argument.

Comment: @JBNizet I do not have problems of thread Safty. I creat an instance each time. An anti-pattern, how ?

Comment: As I said: you're using instnce fields not to store the state of the object, but as a temporary storage for a specific method call: the state is useless before it's called, and useless after it's called, so its scope should be the method, not the object.

Comment: Ah, that is different, and cleaner. I'm not sure there is a pattern name for this though.

Comment: A non-trivial class with all methods but one being private is quite normal. A parser, for instance, is likely of this form. I don't know of a name for it (this question). Usually it would be implemented with either an anonymous inner class (no argument copying) or an outer class (sensible indents).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline what you mena by sensible indents ?

Comment: The third parameter `params` has nothing to do
in your Compiling process. I think that there is someting to refactor with
`Object o` and `Object params`. I guess that should be a `Map` where params are the key and object contains values ?

Comment: This is just an exemple @HalayemAnis i’ve modified the original code to illustrate the problem

Comment: [Prof. Bernhard Pfahringer](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~bernhard/) on University of Waikato mention "tramp data" in a [course](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~bernhard/314/) as `code smell` (see [slides](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~bernhard/314/Refactoring.pdf) at page 5).

Comment: Here is another one by [Martin Fowler - Trade Offs To Parameterizing](https://martinfowler.com/articles/refactoring-dependencies.html#TradeOffsToParameterizing) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version of your code where you were passing parameters repeatedly down through the call-stack is referred to as "tramp data". You can read about it in [a similar question on the Software Engineering site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/335005/210373). What I think you're *trying* to do is to use [Dependency Injection](https://www.journaldev.com/2394/java-dependency-injection-design-pattern-example-tutorial). I say "trying" because you're not injecting your dependencies into the `Compiler` instance, itself.

Instead, I would argue that what you're actually using is a *really small* version of the [Bounded Context pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). By this, I mean that your `InnerCompiler` class is a bounded context as described in Domain-Driven Design and might be more aptly named: `CompilerContext`. That being said, bounded contexts are usually domain level constructs that you are using to encapsulate complicated service-level data sets. A set of three parameters don't usually merit the term "bounded context", but that threshold is pretty subjective IMO, and you might be oversimplifying your code here for the sake of an easily understandable MCVE.

To use the DI pattern in a more standard form, I would change your code to something like the following:

```java
public class Compiler {

  private final String template;
  private final Object o;
  private final Object params;

  Compiler(String template, Object o, Object params) {
    this.template = template;
    this.o = o;
    this.params = params;
  }

  public void compile() {
    //...
    context();
    //...
  }

  private void context() {
    //...
    substitute();
    //...
  }

  private void substitute() {
    //...
    print();
    //...
  }

  private void print() {
    //...
    System.out.println(this.params);
    //...
  }
}
```

This achieves what you're doing right now, without resorting to an artificial inner class.

Note that if you truly need something like a compiler to be used as a singleton as you have in your version of the code, consider using a `CompilerFactory` class with a `newCompiler()` method which would call the constructor and inject the dependencies.

I hope this answers your question. I know that this answer isn't a pattern out of the Design Patterns book by the Gang of Four, but IMO none of the patterns in that book truly reflect your code or your intent.

Comment: **tramp data** that's what I'm looking for. But there's nothing more about it on the internet! is it something related to [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/335005/210373) ? Is there another way to fix it ?

Answer (score -2):

What you are trying to do seems to me to change parameter passing to global state.

Comment: can you develop ?